# VHDL: Reversing every 8 bit in a std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a very long std_logic_vector of size 752. 
Every 8 bits in this vector needs to be reversed for a function.
So

```
a(0) <= b(7)
a(1) <= b(6)
a(2) <= b(5)
a(3) <= b(4)
a(4) <= b(3)
a(5) <= b(2)
a(6) <= b(1)
a(7) <= b(0)
```

And then reversing it for the next 8 bits

```
a(8) <= b(15)
a(9) <= b(14)
a(10) <= b(13)
a(11) <= b(12)
a(12) <= b(11)
a(13) <= b(10)
a(14) <= b(9)
a(15) <= b(8)
```

And this just goes on like this for every 8 bits till 752. Is there a better way to do this? I was thinking of using a for loop within a for loop. The first loop is used for checking whether the element if a divisible by multiples of 8-1 , and the second for loop is for reversing the values every 8 bits.

Comment: The double loop should work.

Comment: @BrianDrummond do you think this would take too much resources on the FPGA with such a double loop?

Comment: Tell me what you find, And compare it with a double "for ... generate" outside a process.

Comment: @holyprinter: In the FPGA it is just wire renaming that is resolved at compile time, so it won't take any resources in the FPGA.

Comment: While these assignments don't consume logic resources how do you simulate efficiently? 752 concurrent assignment statements mean 752 processes post elaboration each with a sequential assignment, all sensitive to `b` regardless of whether the value of the `a` output is affected. You want the number of  processes equal to the number of times it takes you to assign all of `b` each sensitive to a unique signal event. Your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for solving that. Big things can eat simulation resources.

Comment: I think that maybe your actual problem might be your data structure. Structures such as "array of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)" and/or "array of std_logic_vector(0 to 7)" can help make more sense of your code, and possibly even avoid your bit reversing problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to split the input into chunks of 8 bits and do the reverse only within each chunk:

```
process(b)
begin
  for chunk in 0 to (752/8)-1 loop
    for i in 0 to 7 loop
      a(8*chunk+i) <= b(8*chunk+(7-i));
    end loop;
  end loop;
end process;
```